# Is the guaranteed four star always the last hero drawn?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

When you're guaranteed a 4★ Ultra Rare unit from a Gacha, will it always be the last awarded?

Comment: I can't speak for this game since I don't play it, but in my experience with similar games, the guaranteed draw is usually the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the last unit drawn will always be the guaranteed unit.